# Вывести средством css сообщение о неверности поля почты

Tags: css, валидация

```
<label for="email">email</label>
<input type="email" name="email" class="newTask__email" required />
```

для `input[type=email]:invalid` только с css нужно вывести сообщение о ошибке валидации.

```
input[type=email]:invalid+label:before {
   color: red;
   content: "email не валиден";
}
```

это дает сообщению висеть все время в фаерфокс, в хроме вообще не показывает.

как это нормально сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С такой разметкой, как в вопросе, невозможно добиться поставленной задачи только с помощью CSS.

1. В теге `<label>` атрибут `for` принимает значение атрибута `id` (не `name`!), того элемента, к которому привязывается. У Вас атрибут `id` в теге `<input>` не указан.
2. Селектор `+` в данном правиле (`input[type=email]:invalid + label:before`) подразумевает наличие тега `<label>` сразу за тегом `<input>`. У Вас они стоят наоборот.

Ниже  приведён очень "костыльный" вариант, но похоже, что единственный. При этом, разметку всё же нужно править. (В вашем случае, подход - только CSS - изначально неверный.)

```css
input[type=email]:invalid+label::after {
  content: "E-mail не валиден";
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 100%;
  padding: 3px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

label {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  padding: 3px;
}
```

```html
<input type="email" id="email_1" name="email_1" class="newTask__email" autocomplete="new-password" required />
<label for="email_1">E-mail</label>
<br><br><br>
<input type="email" id="email_2" name="email_2" class="newTask__email" autocomplete="new-password" required pattern="\b[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+\.\w{2,4}\b" />
<label for="email_2">E-mail</label>
<br><br><br>
<input type="email" id="email_3" name="email_3" class="newTask__email" autocomplete="new-password" pattern="\b[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+\.\w{2,4}\b" />
<label for="email_3">E-mail</label>
```

Comment: спасибо. еще добавил :-moz-ui-invalid:not([value=""])

Comment: @CodeGust: был рад помочь. А Мозиллу запускаю редко - тормозит и падает она часто в последнее время. А так да, надо бы добавлять префиксы. Удачи.

Comment: проблема оказалась - все время видно сообщ., даже когда не введено ничего. Исчезает только когда валидно.
у меня мозила наоборот отлично работает...

Comment: @CodeGust: всё верно - пустое поле - это некорректный e-mail.

Comment: да, но сообщ. появляется сразу после загрузки стр., до того, как поставить фокус на поле...

Comment: @CodeGust: обновил. Сравните варианты, найдите различия в логике, разберитесь в коде.